# What the parameters 'maxAMShare' in yarn fair-scheduler.xml mean?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, scheduler

in yarn fair-scheduler.xml:
maxAMShare: limit the fraction of the queue’s fair share that can be used to run application masters. This property can only be used for leaf queues. For example, if set to 1.0f, then AMs in the leaf queue can take up to 100% of both the memory and CPU fair share. The value of -1.0f will disable this feature and the amShare will not be checked. The default value is 0.5f.

What the parameters 'maxAMShare' limit ?? only limit  The submitted total appmaster memory and CPU? Computing Resources  not limit？

if i set all queue's maxAMShare=0.5f,What's going to happen？if my total resources 320G+80cpu,How many I can use ？

i find i only use half total resources in yarn,i don't know what's happen ，so doubt 'maxAMShare'